# Does anyone know how to spell this phrase to make it in a correct form/structure?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, technical-terminology

Does anyone know how to spell this phrase to make it in a correct form/structure?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Weiß jemand, wie man diesen Satz buchstabiert, um ihn in die richtige Form/Struktur zu bringen?

Vielen Dank im Voraus für Ihre Hilfe.

--

Das Essen ist fertig. (+)

Im Kühlschrank sind Wein, Wasser und Limonade (von links nach rechts). (+)

Der Stand ist aufgebaut. (+)

Der ___ ist aufgespannt. (?)

Die Tische und Bänke sind aufgestellt. (+)

Ich habe in der [Suchmaschine gesucht](https://www.hornbach.de/projekte/markisen-auswaehlen-und-montieren/), aus welchen Teilen die Marquise (Ständer) besteht, aber immer noch nicht das richtige Wort gefunden.

[image]

Ich habe versucht, diese Wörter zu ersetzen:

1. Der Tafel (m.)
2. Der Leinwand (m.)
3. Der Schaft (Z.b., in der context als: Der Schaft mit Acrylgewebe) (m.)
4. Der Webstoff (m.)

Aber es hat mir nicht geholfen.

I searched in the [search engine](https://www.hornbach.de/projekte/markisen-auswaehlen-und-montieren/) for what parts the marquise (stand) consists of, but still did not find the right word.

I tried to substitute these words:

1. Der Tafel (m.)
2. Der Leinwand (m.)
3. Der Schaft (context was: Der Schaft mit Acrylgewebe) (m.)
4. Der Webstoff (m.)

But it didn't help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Vielen Dank im Voraus für Ihre Hilfe.

Das ist richtig.

> Der ___ ist aufgespannt. (?)

Dieses Ding wird im allgemeinen *der Sonnenschirm* genannt. Markisen werden hingegen an einer Wand, meist oberhalb eines Fensters, befestigt.

Der Sonnenschirm in deinem Bild hat einen beschwerten Fuß oder Sockel. Darin eingesteckt ist sein Schaft und oben aufgesteckt ist der Baldachin. Der Baldachin selbst besteht aus einem Gerippe oder Gestell und der Bespannung aus Stoff.

> Die Tafel

Eine Tafel ist ein langer Tisch, auf dem Essen und Trinken serviert werden.

> Die Leinwand

Dieses Wort wird für ein Webmaterial verwendet, das eine sogenannte Leinwandbildung hat. Genau dieselbe Zahl von Schuss- und Kettfäden, immer abwechselnd. Das ist für Leinwände zum Bemalen genau richtig. Allerdings ist so ein Stoff sehr steif, so dass man kaum etwas anderes als Leinwände, Segel, Planen, Markisen und eben Bespannungen von Sonnenschirmen daraus machen kann.

> Der Schaft mit Acrylgewebe

Der Schaft ist normalerweise aus Metall oder Holz und ist nicht in ein Gewebe eingepackt.

> Der Webstoff

Ein Stoff, der gewebt wurde. Alternativen sind zum Beispiel häkeln oder stricken.